# Django 2.0 - KeyError on View Test for Login

Tags: python, django, django-unittest

I'm having some problems testing my Django application. I have a view that gets information from a login form and then validate / authenticate the user, therefore redirecting him to a home view that displays various informations. I also put a control so that when the user is not logged in and he tries to insert the URL "/home" it redirects him to a errorpage view that displays an error template.

This is the getLogin view, called when the form in the "login.html" page is submitted. I won't show the showLoginTemplate view because it basically does only that.

```
def getLogin(request):
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    ...
    # operations and context creation
    ...
    return render(request, 'myapp:home', context)
else:
    if request.method == "POST":
        email = request.POST['mail']
        password = request.POST['psw']
        user = authenticate(request, username=email, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            auth_login(request, user) #the Django login renamed as auth_login
            ...
            # operations and context creation
            ...
            return redirect("/home", context)
        else:
            return redirect('/login/error', errorLogin='error')
            # shows the same page but with a login error message
    else:
        return redirect("myapp:errorpage")
```

The home view:

```
def home(request):
   if request.user.is_authenticated:
       # operations and context creation
       return render(request, 'users/home.html', context)
   else:
       return redirect("myapp:errorpage")
       #goes into a error page
```

This is the test I'm trying (among other)

```
    def testHomeWithLogin(self):
       user = User.objects.create(username="qwerty@gmail.com", 
              email="qwerty@gmail.com", password="qwerty")
       print(user.username)
       response = self.client.post("/login/#", {
        "mail": "qwerty@gmail.com", "psw": "qwerty"
       })
       print(response.context["mail"])
```

I'm getting a "KeyError": 'mail' " in the last line, like it doesn't get the post data.
Am I doing something wrong with the view or is it the test?

Comment: I don't understand why you think `response.context` would contain "mail". I can't see anywhere where you are are rending a template with "mail" in the context. Are you getting confused between template context and POST arguments? But why would you want to verify the POST arguments, since they are what you passed in the test itself?

Comment: I only tried to print something to verify that I was doing things correctly, later I would have added more line of codes to assert something about the correct login. So how can I get the post arguments?

Comment: But why do you want to? They are what you passed in the previous line. What would be the value of this? What would it be testing?

Comment: I want to test if the user logged in correctly

Comment: Fine, but how would checking that you passed "mail" in the POST achieve that?

Comment: As I said, that was a test, just to say "it's printing the correct e-mail, I've done everything right